# Rattling noise after break pad, disk and caliper change

Tags: bmw, brake-calipers, brake-pad, disk-brakes, caliper

I own a BMW 3 series 2008 318i.

I got my rear break pad and disks changed as well as the caliper changed on the rear left 2 days ago.

A day later driving home i noticed rattling noises coming from rear left, what could this be?

A few days later
I went back to the garage, he went for a drive and told me he couldint hear anything (unfortunately it was raining at the time). So he took it back inside then he jacked up the car and spun the wheels at 20mph, he told me he could not hear any rattling, neither could i to be fair.

So what is this rattling noise im hearing from the rear left area. Its easily noticeable at low speeds. He said it could be because your handbrake cables are stretched? Its something Ive mentioned to him before that the handbrake now needs to go up further than usual to prevent the car from rolling.

Im not sure if i should get this guy to fix my handbrake cables when im hearing this noise after his previous fix. Could it be because i neeed new handbrake cables? Is this even plausible?

Comment: Caliper fixing bolts left loose?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if they didn't install the anti rattle clip that comes with the pads? That will cause what you are describing.  Also, it wouldn't make noise by just spinning the wheel.  It would happen when hitting bumps.  Additionally, I believe you can adjust the hand brake cable and tighten it up.  If you don't use the handbrake a lot I would doubt it's stretched anyway.  Sounds like he's not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Right i notice at high speed the rattling doesent happen is that because its not hitting bumps? So could it be these anti rattle clips? Im going to another garage soon to them to check it out what should i mention to them?

Comment: I would think you would notice it more driving slower around town.  Another thing to try:. Each time you press the brake it should tighten the pads against the rotor and quiet the noise.  If you press on the brake and the noise stops then probably a rattling pad.  If not then the search continues.

Answer (score 0):

i try what i have in my knowledge

if the hand brakes stretched your tire will be hot enough and will smoke or smell like burning rubber. it's very dumb statement. because both will be rattling or hot

try jack the car and check your tire it should be rolled by hand (at neutral gear) without so much force.

if the rattling comes because you drive it, try to asking him join you to to drive and hear it, if the sound occurs. jack it, check your tire if low pressure or there is small bump that makes your tire sounds like hitting rock road.

try to shake your tire with your hand while the car jacked, if a bit shakes, there is 60% your tire bearing loose because it didn't tight enough or it could be your bearing is damaged.

and yes he could be forget to install the clip. because he doesn't thinks it has to be installed.